# How to find A in a Matrix multiplication Ax=b, with some Values of A known, and A being left stochastic

Tags: python, matrix, solver

I have been trying to find an answer to this problem for a couple of hours now, but i can't find anything so far...

So I have two vectors let's call them b and x, of which i know all values. They add up to be the same amount, so `sum(b) = sum(x)`.

I also have a Matrix, let's call it A, of which i know what values are 0, all the other values are unknown (but are different from 0).

Furthermore, the the elements of each column of A has the sum of 1 (I think that's called it's a left stochastic matrix)

Generally the Equation can be written in the form `A*x = b`.

Now I'm trying to find the missing values of A.

I have found one answer to the general problem here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1170843/solving-ax-b-when-x-and-b-are-given

Furthermore i looked at the documentation of numpy.linalg
:https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/routines.linalg.html, but i just can't figure out how to do it.

It looks similar to a multi linear regression problem, but also on sklearn, i couldn't find anything: https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression.html#sklearn.linear_model.LinearRegression

Answer (score 0):

Not a complete answer, but a bit of a more formal statement of the problem.

I think this can be solved as just a system of linear equations. Let

```
NZ = {(i,j)|a(i,j) is not fixed to zero}
```

Then write:

```
sum( j | (i,j) ∈ NZ,  a(i,j) * x(j) ) = b(i)  ∀i
sum( i | (i,j) ∈ NZ,  a(i,j)) = 1  ∀j
```

This is just a system of linear equations in `a(i,j)`. It may be under- (or over-) determined and it may be sparse. I think it depends a bit on this how to solve it. It may possible to think about these as constraints in a linear (or quadratic) programming problem. That would allow you to add an objective (in case of an underdetermined system or overdetermined -- in that case minimize sum of squared deviations, or 1-norm of deviations). In addition we can add bounds on `a(i,j)` (e.g. lower bounds of zero and upper bounds of one). So a linear programming approach may be what you are looking for.

This problem looks a bit like **matrix balancing**. This is used a lot for economic data sets that come from different sources and where we want to reconcile the data to get a consistent data set usable for subsequent modeling.